# Angularjs ng-click not firing under ng-bind-html-unsafe

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

This is the directive

```
aomApp.directive('aomAlert', function ($rootScope,$compile) {
return {
    restrict:'EA',
    transclude:true,
    replace:true,
    scope: {type: '=', msgCollection: '=', close: '&'},
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs,$compile) {
        $scope.show = false;

        $scope.$watch('msgCollection', function(selectedPlan) {
            $scope.show = ($scope.msgCollection.length > 0);
        });                     
    },
    template: 
        "<div class='alert' ng-class='type && \"alert-\" + type' ng-show='show'>" +
        "   <button ng-show='closeable' type='button' class='close' ng-click='show = false;close();'>&times;</button>" +
        "   <ul>" +  
        "       <div ng-repeat='msg in msgCollection'><li><div ng-bind-html-unsafe=msg></div></li></div>"+
        "   <ul>" +  
        "</div>",
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.closeable = "close" in $attrs;

    }


};
```

});

and in the controller I put the link into the msg var

```
msg = msg.replace("[", "<a href='javascript:return false' ng-click='alert()'>");
                msg = msg.replace("]", "</a>");
```

However the ng-click doesnt get triggered
Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting something into html-bind-unsafe doesn't compile it. You'd have to tell the element to compile with the scope. Here's the docs on $compile: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

**edit** Ok, you don't need to use $compile from your responses in the comments. There are two ways of going about doing this, one is you tell clickme to call $parent.clickme on the scope:

```
scope.clickme = function(){
    scope.$parent.clickme();
};
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4ang/3/

The other is you pass in clickme as an attribute, directive:

```
scope: { 
    data: '=',
    clickme: '='
},
```

Html

```
<toggle-buttons data="data" clickme="clickme"></toggle-buttons>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4ang/4/

Comment: I went through the doc , but still got confused about this issue, i have tried compiling the html-bind-unsafe in the template like this:   <div ng-repeat='msg in msgCollection'><li>"+$compile("<div ng-bind-html-unsafe=msg></div>")+"</li></div>".   But it still doesn't work

Comment: No, you'll have to do it in your directive after. Why are you using html-bind-unsafe in this manner? It's usually reserved for things not part of angular.

Comment: what do you mean by do it in directive after ? can you give me the code for that ? thanks for your reply

Comment: Set up a jsFiddle and i'll wire it together if i can.

Comment: I created a simple one here http://jsfiddle.net/a4ang/, basically i want to call the clickme() in the controller instead of calling it within the directive. Now it is not firing when i click on the button

Comment: Hi Mathew, just one more question, i modify your code a little bit with 'ng-bind-html-unsafe'. That's exactly what my app is doing, I still can't figure out a way to make it work, could you please help?http://jsfiddle.net/64awb/